# Call interface web service vs2015

Tags: c#, methods, interface

I have the following WSdl in vs2015 http://aereo.contravel.grupoiris.net/LoginServiceService?wsdl the service reference was completed ok.

i need to pass login and password to get a id value.. how can i call the LoginService interface because has a method dologin(user, password).. please review the image .. thanks for your help

[reference image in vs2015](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77Uhi.png)

Comment: i created loginrequest             ServiceReferenceFlight.LoginRequest lr = new LoginRequest()
            {
                Login = "login",
                Password = "password"
            };

Comment: and dologinrequest()             doLoginRequest dlr = new doLoginRequest()
            {
                arg0 = lr
            };

Comment: my problem is when i try to create the interface to call the method dologin() LoginService instance = new LoginService(); 
            instance.doLogin(dlr);

Comment: i have the followin error C#: Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface

Comment: This is the solution:             LoginServiceClient s = new LoginServiceClient();
            string id = s.doLogin(lrequest).Uuid;